# Python looping code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
total = 0          
gradeCounter = 0  
numbers = []
grade = input("Enter grade, -1 to end:")   # get one grade
grade = int(grade)   # convert string to an integer

while grade != -1:
    total = total + grade
    gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1
    grade = input( "Enter grade, -1 to end: " )
    grade = int( grade )

if gradeCounter != 0:
    average = float( total ) / gradeCounter
    print('Largest is {}, smallest is {}'.format(max(numbers), min(numbers)))
    print ("Class average is", average)
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could fix my coding. I'm trying to find a simple way to print the lowest and highest integer that the user input. What I have found isn't working an I suspect It's because I'm using Python3+. I'd like it to fit in with the coding I have already placed but yeah the code I have used isn't working.

I'm trying to find the code so my program (which a user puts in school grades) finds the avarge (done) lowest and highest and prints them.. The lowest and highest bits are what I can't do. –

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: Thankyou for the welcome, I'm sorry for my bad explanation I'm autistic so thats the best way I found myself I could explain it in. I'm trying to find the code so my program (which a user puts in school grades) finds the avarge (done) lowest and highest and prints them.. The lowest and highest bits are what I can't do.

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to add more information. What is missing here is how the code is not working. What input did you give, and what output did you expect? What happened instead? Did you get any errors? If so, include the *full* traceback for those. Help us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the lines

```
if grade != -1:
    numbers.append(grade)
```

after  `grade = int(grade)`. This adds the grade to the list `numbers`.

### Review

- Use [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (you can use pep8online.com) to check your code
- For unnamed input, I prefer `"Largest is %i, smallest is %i" % (max(numbers), min(numbers))`
- You can use `sum` to sum up integers in a list
- If you add a shebang (the first line `#!/usr/bin/env python`), then Linux users can execute your script directly like this: `./yourscript.py` instead of `python yourscript.py`.

### Code

I would rather write the code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def get_grades():
    """Return a list of grades."""
    numbers = []
    while True:
        grade = int(input("Enter grade, -1 to end: "))
        if grade != -1:
            numbers.append(grade)
        else:
            return numbers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    grades = get_grades()
    if len(grades) != 0:
        average = float(sum(grades)) / len(grades)
        print('Largest is %i, smallest is %i.' % (max(grades), min(grades)))
        print("Class average is %0.2f." % average)
```

### Reading error messages

You probably had the following:

```
$ python test.py 
Enter grade, -1 to end:1
Enter grade, -1 to end: 2
Enter grade, -1 to end: 3
Enter grade, -1 to end: -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print('Largest is {}, smallest is {}'.format(max(numbers), min(numbers)))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Now you should first look for line number. This one says in `line 15` is something wrong. This is:

```
print('Largest is {}, smallest is {}'.format(max(numbers), min(numbers)))
```

Now you have to investigate further. What exactly is wrong? What could possibly go wrong in this line?

Now you read

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

That should look strange, because you checked `gradeCounter != 0`. Next, you would print the contents of the argument of max. This is empty, so adding to the list `numbers` did not work.

Comment: @BellaSilvermoon You're welcome. If the answer helped you / you found it good, you should upvote it. If it answered your question, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `grade` to the list of `numbers` like so: `numbers.append(grade)` otherwise your list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks faster way is add all the user input data in some list and then sorted that list

```
>>> list = [3, 1, 9, 8, 6]
>>> sorted(list)
[1, 3, 6, 8, 9]
>>> sorted(list, reverse = True)
[9, 8, 6, 3, 1]
>>> list
[3, 1, 9, 8, 6]
```

then you can print the list[0] and list[len(list)-1]